# Progress in ajax while uploading 2 files or more

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file

Hi Im trying to upload a 2 file or more, my problem is my progress bar will say 100% because of the small file being uploaded first, then its going back to the percent of the large file.. My question is how can I have a same progress if i have many files being uploaded?

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = files.files[i]; i++) {

 $.ajax({

     xhr: function(){
        //upload Progress
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                var percent = 0;
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total = event.total;
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                }
                //update progressbar
                $('.bar').width(percent + '%');
            }, true);
        }
        return xhr;
    },
               url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
               type: 'post',
               data: f,
               processData: false,
               contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
               headers: {
                         "Authorization": "Bearer ACCESS TOKEN",
                         "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/'+f.name+'", "mode": "add","autorename": true,"mute": false}'
                         },
               success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
              app.alert.show('success-message', {
                 level: 'success',
                  messages: 'your file has been upload to Dropbox',
               autoClose: true
                   });
               },
               error: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               }
               })

               }
```

Comment: from what i can see you are ajaxing each file individually so you need a progress bar for each

Comment: Is there a way only 1 progress bar and can read the upload of all files?

Comment: yes but you will need to calculate the total size of all the files

Comment: inside of xhr too?

Comment: yes man this is simple math

Comment: Okay thanks! ill try it now

Comment: I would suggest you use a library, something like this https://github.com/danielm/uploader

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store progress of each file in different variable (or maybe array of variables) and write function, that will update progressbar width when this vars are changed.